# Binary Form Of any File Format

Tags: java, binary, integer

I'm writing a method to get any file format into binary format. I am using following lines of code. But I'm not getting how is it working. if anybody knows these how these lines work kindly elaborate it.
Here are the lines.

```
String s= "0000000" +Integer.toBinaryString(new FileInputStream(File File1).read());
s=s.substring(s.length()-8);
```

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: "I'm writing a method to get any file format into binary format" - doesn't make much sense. Could you elaborate on that specification?

Comment: File Format for example let it be image1.jpg. I want to convert this file into a stream of binary Strings of 8 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Since you now tagged your answer as Java, you could use `Files.readAllBytes(Path)` to read a file into a byte array (from JDK 7 on):

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;

Path path = Paths.get("path/to/my/file");
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

---

Assuming you are using C#, you can load a file into a byte array using `File.ReadAllBytes` as follows:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\path\to\my\file.jpg");
```

Note that you normally would not use strings when dealing with binary data such as image files.

Comment: Thanks for your kind effort.

Answer (score 0):

An integer is read, converted to a string of its binary representation, and 8 0's are added to the front, so that regardless of how small the original value was, you have at least 8 characters of a valid binary representation.  Thus, what is assigned to s is the binary representation with as many leading zeros as needed to pad it out to 8 characters by taking the last 8 characters of the concatenation described above.

Comment: Kindly explain the second line as well.

Comment: @MohsinAli: Thanks. If you like an answer, you can show this on StackOverflow by upvoting the answer.